# Meta theory of the "fruit of the poisonous tree" doctrine

Tags: reference-request

Where can I read more about the meta-theory behind the "fruit of the poisonous tree" doctrine, e.g. what the rationale and purposes of this doctrine are, what makes it legitimate, where it fits within the philosophy of law. I'm not interested in the specifics of what form the doctrine takes in, say, US law. I'm interested in general philosophical considerations of the principles behind this doctrine, which are not tied to any particular legal system. I'm interested in understanding if the doctrine might be applicable in other areas, not necessarily criminal law.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://philosophy.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Rick I'm looking for reference works in the field of the philosophy of law on the subject of the "Fruit of the Poisonous Tree" doctrine: the approach that certain products of a process that feed into another process should be excluded as input to the second process based on the manner in which the products were procured, rather than on their inherent qualities. And specifically, the applicability of this principle to the fields of law (not necessarily criminal law) and governance.

Comment: @Rick I don't understand.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch philosophy of law is on topic here (and also on Philosophy SE).

Comment: Yes, let's please keep this open. Questions about the law seem like a pretty good fit for law.SE.

Comment: is it not as simple as: if it was legal to use the results of illegal searches, cops would do illegal searches a lot more often?